# Helm upgrade get currently deployed chart version

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When running `helm upgrade...`, I'd like to be able to detect the currently deployed Chart version so I can set specific template values based on it.

Something like `{{ Release.ChartVersion }}` or `{{ Chart.InstalledVersion }}`.

I'm familiar with the [official guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/), but was not able to find a way to do this.

Comment: You might have to do this as a 2 parter. running `helm status` to get the data and then running update based on the results

Comment: It has to be in the template so I can get it at the `helm upgrade` and without any scripting before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately running helm upgrade not check the currently installed version, just run an upgrade. 
But you can check installed version by running: `helm ls`.
You'll see the table of installed packages in the cluster. You can find and check the chart version:

```sh
MY_PACKAGE_VERSION=$(helm ls | grep 'my-best-chart-name' | awk '{ print $10 }')
```